# How to start js-function with arguments in HTML-page

Tags: javascript

I want to simplify the javascript in the HTML-page below. How do I start function FrameUpdate with 2 arguments? 
In this way I don't have to repeat the script for every HREF-action on my HTML-page.

Thanks,
Sjoerd

```
<html>

<A HREF="geenscript.html" onclick="FrameUpdate3005(); return false;">Update 3005</A>
<p>
  <A HREF="geenscript.html" onclick="FrameUpdate3017(); return false;">Update 3017</A>


  <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function FrameUpdate3005() {
      parent.boven.location.href = "3005-n.htm";
      parent.onder.location.href = "3005-t.htm";
    }
    //-->
  </SCRIPT>


  <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function FrameUpdate3017() {
      parent.boven.location.href = "3017-n.htm";
      parent.onder.location.href = "3017-t.htm";
    }
    //-->
  </SCRIPT>

</html>
```

Comment: If all that's is changing is the number, you'd only need 1 parameter, what's the second one for?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do the job :

```
<a href="geenscript.html" onclick="FrameUpdate(3005); return false;">Update 3005</a>

<a href="geenscript.html" onclick="FrameUpdate(3017); return false;">Update 3017</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FrameUpdate(value) {
        parent.boven.location.href = `${value}-n.htm`;
        parent.onder.location.href = `${value}-t.htm`;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change FrameUpdate3005() to:

```
<A HREF="geenscript.html" onclick="FrameUpdate3005(param1Value,param2Value); return false;">Update 3005</A>
```

and

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function FrameUpdate3005(param1,param2) {
    // logic that uses param1 and param2
    parent.boven.location.href = "3005-n.htm";
    parent.onder.location.href = "3005-t.htm";
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to simply make it one function, instead of having a function for each? They seem to want the same result:

```js
function frameUpdate( id ) {

  parent.boven.location.href = id + "-n.htm";
  parent.onder.location.href = id + "-t.htm";

  // Since you always want to return false, why not wrap it in here?
  // No need to add a separate `return false`.
  return false;

}
```

```html
<a href="geenscript.html" onclick="return FrameUpdate( 3005 );">Update 3005</a>
<a href="geenscript.html" onclick="return FrameUpdate( 3017 );">Update 3017</a>
```

A couple of notes though, you are missing the `<body>` tag at least, and `<head>` should also be in there. And your `<p>` tag gets openened and never closed.